# Accepting login parameters in Parse (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication

For my application, it requires the user to login. If the user login is invalid, I need to let the user know that. So I was wondering how to bring up an UIAlertView if the login parameters are invalid. It automatically lets me know in the terminal if its valid or invalid. But I need to know how to create an AlertView so the user knows they entered their information successfully or unsuccessfully.

## CODE

```
IBAction func loginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = usernameField.text
    let password = passwordField.text

    if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
        var emptyFieldsError:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "Please fill in all the fields we can get you logged in to your account.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        emptyFieldsError.show()
    }

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            println("Sucessful")
        } else {
            println("Invalid login")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. :

```
 // Mark: Error message alert.

var errorMessage = String()

func alertView(title: String, message: String, buttonName: String){

    var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonName, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func loginTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName.text, password: password.text) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user != nil {

            // user logged in.. Perform Segue here..

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("a", sender: self)

        } else {

            // Show error here..

            if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? String {
                self.errorMessage = errorString

            }

            self.alertView("Error!", message: self.errorMessage, buttonName: "Try again")

        }


    }

}
```